# Angular возврат инфы с get запроса

Tags: http, angular, get, клиент-сервер, данные

я новичок делающий тестовое задание, у меня есть клиент на angular и сервер на asp.net. Когда я отправляю данные с клиента на сервер при помощи get запроса я получаю ответ 200, но не получаю данные которые возвращает сервер на клиенте. Делал запрос с постмана данные приходят, еще добавил базу данных на сервер которая сохраняет запросы и выяснил что запросы с клиента приходят. Так вот вопрос как на клиенте увидеть ответ с сервера, слышал что-то про метод OnInit, вроде как с помощью него нужно получать эти данные с сервера, объясните пожалуйста как их получить.

```
Код класса AppComponent
response : any;
name: string = "";
tmp: string = "";

constructor(private http: HttpClient){

}

public search(name : string) {
console.log(name);
this.http.get('http://localhost/WebTestServer/Ping/абв')
.subscribe((response)=>{
  this.response = response;
  this.tmp = "ok";
  console.log(this.response);
  console.log(this.tmp);
  })
}
Код html
<div class="container">
<h1>Hello Angular</h1>
<app-card></app-card>
 <input type="text" (input)="inputHandler($event)">
  <button (click)="search(name)">
   Отправить гет
  </button>
  <div *ngIf="response">
  <p>Текст: {{response.data.body}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а `console.log(this.response);` что в консоль пишет?

Comment: добавил скрин с выводом консоли

Comment: он почему-то ничего не выводит

Comment: да запрос идет на сервер и он делает запись в бд с текстом запроса то, что идет после Ping/ и временем запроса, попробую ваш метод, свой я взял из видео с уроками по ангуляру)

Comment: Такой вопрос еще на 2 скрине в request url идет ссылка запроса это нормально что в коде передается Ping/абв, а там иероглифы какие-то

Comment: Проблема в том что мне на клиенте нужно ответ с сервера вывести)), поэтому так оставить не вариант

Comment: По поводу урл и иероглифоф это нормально, наверно, урл кодирование.

Comment: ок не отображается, раскрыть пробовал

Comment: в консоль выводилось поле name, а это поле инициализируется строкой ввода

Comment: Пофиксил проблему, она заключалась в том что политика CORS блокировала доступ данных, для этого необходимо было на сервере установить доступ этой политике, я использовал в качестве сервера asp.net, эта статья помогла решить проблему http://www.techtutorhub.com/article/asp-net-web-api-Access-to-XMLHttpRequest-at-from-origin-has-been-blocked-by-CORS-policy-No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/43

Answer (score 3):

Пофиксил проблему, она заключалась в том что политика CORS блокировала доступ данных, для этого необходимо было на сервере установить доступ этой политике, я использовал в качестве сервера asp.net, эта статья помогла решить проблему
[Статья для устранения проблемы CORS на сервере asp.net](http://www.techtutorhub.com/article/asp-net-web-api-Access-to-XMLHttpRequest-at-from-origin-has-been-blocked-by-CORS-policy-No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/43)